# How do I move FireFox tabs using keyboard on MacOSX?

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

On linux I can move FF tabs using <kbd>Ctrl-PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-PgDn</kbd>.
What do I do on Mac OS X (Darwin)?

Note that I do not even have <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys here.

I can switch between tabs using <kbd>Cmd-Alt-RightArrow</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd-Alt-RightArrow</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd-Shift-[</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd-Shift-]</kbd>, but I want to move the tabs themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't have a <kbd>PgUp</kbd> or <kbd>PgDn</kbd> key, the <kbd>fn</kbd> key is your friend.

To do what you want, in Firefox, use (ready?) <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-fn-UpArrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-fn-DownArrow</kbd>.  At least this works in Firefox 26 on Mac OS 10.8.5.

Plus, you need long fingers ;)